# script is not loading when we came back from one page to that page where script is placed in react

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

this is the script which is i am using
script is placed on navbar and home page navbar script is display all the time but home page script not load when we came from one page to another

````
import '../App.css';
import './hero.css'
import Hero_Img1 from '../images/blob-haikei (2).png'

function HeroSection() {

  

  return (
    <div className='hero-container'>
      <div className="hero_img_container">
      <img src={Hero_Img1} className="hero_img_left" alt="Hero img"/>
      </div>
      <h1>The White Dental</h1>
      <p>We Care For You</p>
     
 <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.lybrate.com/***/****/****/em-wt.js'></script>
  <div className='lybrate-widget' name='dr-sandeep-kumar-jangra-dentist' tabs='ba,cp' btn-text=' Book Appointment '></div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default HeroSection;```
````

Answer (score 0):

You can load `script` dynamically like this:

```
useEffect(() => {
    loadScript('https://www.lybrate.com/***/****/****/em-wt.js');
    loadScript('script.js');
    loadScript('www.google.com/script.js');    
}, [])


const loadScript = (src) => {
    let script = document.createElement('script');
    script.src = src;    
    document.body.append(script);
}
```

Comment: thanks bhai  script is loading but how to put it at desired position on my page

Comment: @deepanshu I am not getting you with the desired position. Can you please explain it?

Comment: when the script is called a button came on page i want to load the button at my desired position on the page the above code suggest by you load the script at navbar but the script is always show in the navbar script is not loading when i put it on some other page i am giving the link of the project https://quirky-yonath-f2c7d6.netlify.app/

Comment: You can keep this code in any page to load the script. I think your button is not coming because when you come the page then your HTML renders first and script takes some time to load. So in this case you can use `script.onload = () => { // here set some flag to true };`  And if this flag is true then only show that button. So this is how your button will be visible once script is loaded fully.

Answer (score 0):

you can do this with custom react hooks.

```
import { useEffect } from 'react';

const useScript = url => {
  useEffect(() => {
        const script = document.createElement('script');
        script.src = url;
        script.async = false;
        document.body.appendChild(script);

//when component unmount it removes appended script 
        return () => {
            document.body.removeChild(script);
        }
    }, [url]);
};

export default useScript;


// Import where we want to use.
import useScript form './useScript';
import React from 'react';

function App() {
useScript('script_path');
  return (
    <></>
  );
}

export default App;
```